# How to put several "reboot" in nohup?

Tags: linux, reboot

We need a oneliner for rebooting systems to ensure that they are really rebooting, because many times, our reboot just hangs and thus we can only resolve that by going into the console. Something like this (the Q is that what syntax error is in here):

```
server:~ # nohup (echo firstrebootcmd; sleep 200 && echo secondrebootcmd)
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `echo'
server:~ #
```

So:

- first we issue a rebooot cmd
- then of course the network disconnects, we cannot type any more commands, thus we need "nohup".
- after 200 seconds, we give out the rebooot command again, so the machine will rebooot.

Comment: try ` instead of `(` and `)` ?

Comment: @imbuedHope ` won't work as it will run it in a subshell first then pass the output to nohup

Comment: Cannot remember if nohup accepts a quoted command ie `nohup "echo; ...; echo"` if not `nohup sh -c "echo; ...; echo"` should work.

Comment: Suggest hiring a sysadmin.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
nohup sh -c "echo firstrebootcmd; sleep 200 && echo secondrebootcmd"
```